# Which function will be called when using tastypie resource

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I want to understand this point.

this is my url: `repositories/api/2/repositories/?format=json`

this is `urls.py`:

```
    repositories_resource = RepositoriesResource()
    (r'^api/2/', include(repositories_resource.urls)),
```

this is `api.py`:

```
class RepositoriesResource(Resource):
  fs_repositories = fields.CharField(attribute='fs_repositories')
  full_path = fields.CharField(attribute='full_path')
  path = fields.CharField(attribute='path')
  permissions = fields.CharField(attribute='permissions')
  perms_read = fields.ListField(attribute='perms_read')
  perms_write = fields.ListField(attribute='perms_write')
  perms_no_access = fields.CharField(attribute='perms_no_access')   

  class Meta:
    resource_name = 'repositories'
    authorization= Authorization()
  def obj_get_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):
    request.GET = request.GET.copy()
    request.GET.update({"output":"json"})

    frs=svn_repositories(request)

    posts = []
    for l in frs.fs_repositories:
        posts.append(dict2obj({'fs_repositories': l,'full_path':l.full_path,'path':l.path,'permissions':l.permissions,'perms_read':l.perms_read,'perms_write':l.perms_write,'perms_no_access':l.perms_no_access }))      
    return posts
```

It works fine, but I want to know why why `obj_get_list` is called even if I don't specify it, and what about if I want to use other functions like `obj_get`? Which function will be called by default?

Answer (score 0):

URL : `repositories/api/2/repositories/?format=json`

will list all  available objects .

Now using `obj_get_list` U can override the way json response will display. you can customize, limit the response (here in your case `posts` json dict )

Comment: but in tastypie there is lots of method not just object_get_list , if i defibed obj_get_list and post_list functions,how can django detect witch one call?

Comment: `obj_get_list, post_list, obj_create` are methods defined by resource module of tastypie . check this : `http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#Resource.get_object_list` . this methods handles by tastypie resource . It will decide which one to call based on url accessed.

Comment: ok, now i want to call other url but using post method from client ajax function like this : $.post(url,...) and not $.get(url,..) , i use tastypie post_list function but it throw forbidden response

Comment: You need to define which HTTP methods your TastyPie resource supports, though I assume you've moved on from this question after 5 years. See the "allowed_methods" resource option in the TastyPie documentation.